# Script: Rename and remove duplicate directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a directory structure with different subdirectories are tailed with version names
like

```
/drivers/i2c_v1     
/drivers/i2c_v1_0
/drivers/i2c_v2_1
/drivers/i2c_v3
/drivers/spi_v1
/drivers/spi_v2
/drivers/spi_v2_0
/drivers/spi_v2_1
```

I need to rename `/drivers/i2c_v3` with `/drivers/i2c` and remove `drivers/i2c_v*` and
`/drivers/spi_v2_1` with `/drivers/spi` and remove `/drivers/spi_v*`

LATEST VERSION NAME SHOULD RENAME WITH VERSION LESS AND REMAINING VERSION-ED ONE'S SHOULD
DELETE.

Any help...

Comment: `ls -v` might be you friend, see e.g. [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html)

Answer (score 1):

```sh
prefixes=$(ls /drivers/*_v* | sed 's/_.*//' | uniq)
for p in $prefixes; do
    all=($(ls -vr ${p}_*))  # Sort in reverse version order
    latest=${all[0]}        # So first one is highest version
    mv $latest /drivers/temp    # Rename it so it won't be deleted by wildcard below
    if [[ ${#all[@]} > 1 ]]; then   # Check that there's more than one version
        rm -rf ${p}_*               # Remove the ones other than latest
    fi
    mv /drivers/temp ${p}   # Rename it to the non-versioned name
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, if your filenames sorts correctly with sort or sort -n

```
fn=$( ls i2c* | sort -r | head -n1 ); mv -f "$fn" i2c; rm -f i2c_*
```